# BufferedImage not returning as an image

Tags: java, image, graphics, draw, bufferedimage

I have a method to paint a image inside a bufferedimage, but when I return the bufferedimage it just shows up as a 200 by 200 black square instead of the image inside of it, which is suppose to be a goldfish. Here's my code:

```
    Image returnGoldfish() {
    BufferedImage bufferedImage = new BufferedImage(200, 200, BufferedImage.TYPE_3BYTE_BGR);
    Graphics g = bufferedImage.getGraphics();

    g.drawImage(imageFishy, x1, y1, null);

    return bufferedImage;
    }
```

If anyone know what  I did wrong, please help. Thanks. Also, my image is set correctly.

```
Image imageFishy = new ImageIcon("I://Picture//fishy.jpg").getImage();
```

It shows up in the paint when I just paint it as imageFishy, without the bufferedImage.

Comment: Are you sure `x1`, `x2` and `imageFishy` are correctly set?

Comment: my x1 = 50, and y1 is also 50. and the imagefishy is corretly set because it shows up in paint when it's just an image.

Comment: One error is that you're not disposing of the Graphics instance inside your returnGoldfish method when you're finished with it.  (g.dispose())

Comment: how do i dispose of it?

Comment: It's still a black square. @GilbertLeBlanc

Comment: You aren't showing enough code for anyone to make any other suggestions.  Provide a complete, **runnable**, example.

Comment: Unrelated, you can simply do `I:/Picture/fishy.jpg`

Comment: Have you tried reading your fishy image using `ImageIO.read(new File("I:/Picture/fishy.jpg"))` rather than using `ImageIcon`? It's usually a little better to tell you what goes wrong...

Answer (score 1):

The reason you're having a hard time is because you're not disposing of the Graphics object.

```
Image returnGoldfish() {

BufferedImage bufferedImage = new BufferedImage(200, 200, BufferedImage.TYPE_3BYTE_BGR);

Graphics g = newImage.createGraphics();
g.drawImage(imageFishy, x1, y1, null);
g.dispose();

return bufferedImage;
}
```

That's assuming x1, y1, and imageFishy are proper and exist.